# Couldn't get lock for .fortify/sca5.10/log/sca.log

Tags: fortify

I am moving fortify to new server and directory structure is slightly different than old server. When i run fortify on new server i get error

`java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /Old_directory_structure/.fortify/sca5.1/log/sca.log`

Seems like i need to update "/new_directory_structure/.fortify/sca5.1/log/sca.log" in some configuration. Tomcat is sitting on top of Fortify. I am fairly new with fortify and do not know where i need to update this.

Please suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Fortify installation directory and locate **fortify-sca.properties** file under core-->config folder.

change the value of "**com.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot**" and add your new path here.

2. ALso change the following value in ***fortify.properties*** file :
   *****com.fortify.WorkingDirectory*****

Hope this helps....